# Getting exception java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 28 bytes

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am using following unix command to generate 128 bit secret key for AES and write it to a file.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/data/key.txt bs=16 count=1
```

I am reading the key from file in java class and using it for encryption/decryption

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(keylocation.getFile()));
String line = null;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  stringBuilder.append(line);
}
String secretKey = stringBuilder.toString();
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
encryptedString = (Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

But i am getting following exception

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 28 bytes
```

Since i am generating 128 bit(16 bytes) key in file, how it is changed to 28 bytes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `Reader`. A `Reader`'s purpose is to read text.

But you want binary here, ie a byte array.

Solution: don't use a `Reader`. Use an `InputStream` and read into a 16-element `byte` array.

Comment: +1, I think to always MD5 hash the selected key would also ensure 128 bits

Comment: @PopoFibo If your key is a string, then it should either be a binary key encoded using hexadecimals or base 64 of the correct size. It should otherwise be handled as a password. Passwords should be converted to keys using a Password Based Key Derivation Function such as PKCS#5/PBKDF2, not just MD5.

Comment: @owlstead makes perfect sense I was just thinking in terms of the key size though

Answer (score 0):

urandom generates a chunk of bytes that contain nonprintable characters. Using a buffered reader and reading as Java UTF-8 can cause problems probably is getting some bytes as control characters and making more data due to encoding conversions.

Using an InputStream should solve the problem getting bytes instead the string or you should try to create a readable key using other command like:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9_ < /dev/urandom | head -c 16 > /data/key.txt
```